# Using tab controls

Tags: c#, tabs, mschart

I have a tab control which contains a set of controls like list boxes,buttons and a chart control. Is there a possibility of adding another tab, making the new tab to comprise of all the controls that the first tab contained.?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266589/clone-controls-c-sharp-winform

Comment: @Vlad L Thank you for the idea.It would work fine. But in my case i need to create multiple such tabs containing the controls. And i do not know before run time how many such tabs would be needed. So is there a way to do this?

Comment: so you want to create multiple tabs with exactly the same content?

Comment: @Vlad L Yes, you are right. I need the same controls. Though small content changes would be there. For example, the chart content could be different in each tab.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment you are better to create a [usercontrol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1). After creating it once, you can simply add it to the new tab like this:

```
TabPage tp = new TabPage("new tp");

MyUserControl muc = new MyUserControl();
tp.Controls.Add(muc);

tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);

int tabIndex = 1;
```

You can access the properties of each tab like this:

```
int tabIndex = 1;
MyUserControl contr = tabControl1.TabPages[tabIndex].Controls[0] as MyUserControl;
contr.MyGraph = ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works for me. But could i know how i can access the controls of the second tab using code?