# Cloning a panel inside a FlowPanel

Tags: vb.net, panel

I'm  trying  to clone multiple times a panel inside a FlowPanel... But it only clone once.

```
Dim NewFormConta1 As New Panel
NewFormConta1 = Panel1
PanelLateral.Controls.Add(NewFormConta1)

Dim NewFormConta2 As New Panel
NewFormConta2 = Panel1
PanelLateral.Controls.Add(NewFormConta2)

Dim NewFormConta3 As New Panel
NewFormConta3 = Panel1
PanelLateral.Controls.Add(NewFormConta3)
```

Result:

[image]

What I need:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because these assignments are reference assignments

```
NewFormConta1 = Panel1
NewFormConta2 = Panel1
NewFormConta3 = Panel1
```

so your "new" panels all reference the same one panel. You only have one panel but 4 references to it.

```vb
' NewFormConta1 is a new panel
Dim NewFormConta1 As New Panel

' NewFormConta1 points to Panel1 so the new panel from the first line
' is not referenced anymore and will be garbage collected
NewFormConta1 = Panel1

' Panel1 is really added
PanelLateral.Controls.Add(NewFormConta1)
```

How do you populate Panel1? You could populate each NewFormConta the same way.

Or another idea would be to make a User Control which has in it a Panel and the labels. You can modify the label properties with Public Properties in the User Control. Then just do this

```vb
Dim NewFormConta1 As New UserControl1
PanelLateral.Controls.Add(NewFormConta1)
```

Comment: @dr.null like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10266589/832052)? Considering even that won't capture the labels on it, and it may be a little too complicated anyway, probably not worth it