# Duplicating a TextBox in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I was wondering how I would duplicate a `TextBox`, not just the text inside of it.
`TextBox.copy` copies the text selected inside the TextBox, which is not quite what I need.
I am using [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net).

Comment: Just instantiate a new Textbox and initialize it with the same properties as the one that you want to duplicate. Dim textBox As New TextBox

Comment: did you try this? [How to Clone/Serialize/Copy & Paste a Windows Forms Control](https://www.codeproject.com/kb/miscctrl/controlclonetst.aspx)

Comment: @Mederic No, i didn't i will now :)

Comment: There's [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473597/it-is-possible-to-copy-all-the-properties-of-a-certain-control-c-window-forms) about copying properties.

Comment: You can create extension to clone any control like in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10267292/1662459

Answer (score 2):

Please try this function :)

```
Private Function CopyControl(ByVal obj As Object, Optional ByVal locationX As Integer = 0, Optional ByVal locationY As Integer = 0) As Object
    Dim objnew As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(obj.GetType()) 'Create new control
    Dim oldprops As PropertyDescriptorCollection = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj) 'Control properties
    Dim newprops As PropertyDescriptorCollection = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(objnew) 'New control properties
    For i As Integer = 0 To oldprops.Count - 1 '
        newprops(i).SetValue(objnew, oldprops(i).GetValue(obj)) 'New control properties = Old control properties
    Next
    objnew.location = New Point(locationX, locationY) 'Set location
    Return objnew 'New control is copied
    'Im sorry my english is bad, I hope you understand..
End Function
```

---

```
Me.Controls.Add(CopyControl(TextBox1))
```

I'm sorry for my bad english. I'm turkish :D