# Get Clone of TableLayoutPanel for Drag & Drop

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I want to move a TableLayoutPanel and all it's content over my Form. Moving itself is no Problem. I don't want to move the actual Control, when still holding down the Mouse Button but instead I want a faded out copy on my mouse.

My first idea was just to get a copy of the tlp, tweak a bit with Alpha. I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3473722/6002741) for copying my control, but this won't work with a tlp, because of the Settings.

Before I fix this code, i wanted to ask, if there is a easier Method for this. I don't need a working copy of my controls, only a visual copy.

My function should be a general function. I won't know which controls might get added into the tlp. Having a working copy might result in some unwanted events.

Is there a easy function to get a visual copy or do i really need to make a copy and remove all events from the controls of that copy?

Comment: Use its DrawToBitmap() method, fade it with Graphics.FillRectangle().

Comment: Do you mean you want to drag the TLP at run-time, clicking anywhere inside it? Or you have a drag placeholder/marker as the one the TLP shows when you click on it at design-time?

Comment: @Jimi The idea was to drop the TLP in a Panel and when dropped, the code rearanges all TLPs inside that Panel, accordingly. 

My current state is that i place a bitmap copy of the TLP, the original control sticks to the mouse but not visible (needed the mouse move event and changing the alpha doesnt work) . On the Mouse is now a bitmap, that indicates the movement.

I don't care how it's done. It just need to look nice, work and work under .net 2 (not my choice)

Comment: Also I discarded my Idea. Drawing and placing so much in a Form is not that easy. .Net 2.0 and WinForms are not the best idea for this modern design. 
Probably i need to go over the panel mouse move event and not the from tlp.